# GreenDao: how to define a view to be used in android app

Tags: android, greendao

i have the following structure of my database

```
table employee  
emp_id  emp_name
1   a
2   b
3   c


table employee  
emp_id  emp_name
1   a
2   b
3   c


view employee_detail        

emp_id  emp_name emp_address
1   a     w
2   b     q
3   c     r
```

in my greendao generator class , how to add this view as entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know greendao doesn't support views.

If you can change your db-structure you can combine your two tables to one table employee_details.

Otherwise you can create an entity for your view, just as you would do it if it was a normal table. Then you can modify the generated dao to create a view instead of a new table. Be careful with this, as your changes will be overriden upon new greendao-codegeneration.